# Cracked-glass–like plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like make a plot that looks like this:
[image]

Namely a scatter plot with series of replicates connected via lines to the centroid.

I am not sure whether I saw it somewhere or whether I am simply getting glyphplot confused. I do not know what it is called, so Google has failed me —"cracked glass plot" is what I would personally call it.

In Matlab there is no native one line way to show a scatterplot with both x and y errorbars —yet Excel can. This makes me think there is a better way, such as this cracked glass plot.

Does it exist or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any native function to do this, but you can quite easily make use of [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) to plot something to fit your purposes, e.g.

```
function scatterPlotToCentroid(scatterPoints)

    numScatters = size(scatterPoints,2);
    scatterX = scatterPoints(1,:);
    scatterY = scatterPoints(2,:);

    centroid = mean(scatterPoints,2);
    c1 = centroid(1);
    c2 = centroid(2);

    X = [repmat(c1,1,numScatters); scatterX];
    Y = [repmat(c2,1,numScatters); scatterY];

    hold on
    line(X,Y,'Color','k');
    scatter(scatterX, scatterY, 'r*');

end
```

Example call

```
% example: scatter sample (two groups)
numPoints = 10;
scatterDiff = 5;
scatterPointsA = 4+scatterDiff*(rand(2,numPoints)-0.5);
scatterPointsB = 8+scatterDiff*(rand(2,numPoints)-0.5);

% for each scatter sample group, plot scatter points
% and lines to centroid
hold on, box on
scatterPlotToCentroid(scatterPointsA)
scatterPlotToCentroid(scatterPointsB)
axis([0 12 0 12])
```

Example plot

[image]

---

Below follows the initial version of this answer, that left out the "centroid" part of the question (missed...), and instead generated random scatters around a given center-point; drawing lines from the latter to these scatter points.

```
function scatterPlotAt(centerPoint, numScatters, maxScatterSideLength)

    c1 = centerPoint(1);
    c2 = centerPoint(2);

    scatterX = c1-maxScatterSideLength + ...
      randi(2*maxScatterSideLength,1,numScatters);
    scatterY = c2-maxScatterSideLength + ...
      randi(2*maxScatterSideLength,1,numScatters);
    X = [repmat(c1,1,numScatters); scatterX];
    Y = [repmat(c2,1,numScatters); scatterY];
    hold on
    line(X,Y,'Color','k');
    scatter(scatterX, scatterY, 'r*');

end
```

Example call

```
hold on, box on
scatterPlotAt([4; 4], 6, 3)
scatterPlotAt([8; 8], 6, 3)
axis([0 12 0 12])
```

Example result

[image]

Comment: That is fantastic! Thanks!
Also I had no idea `line` accepted matrices.

Comment: @MatteoFerla Updated answer to actually plot lines to the centroid of a given set of scatter points (and not as answer previous to edit---the other way around---; random scatter points from a given center point). Happy to help!